# Last day of previous month in Informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am trying to get the last day of the previous month with the below logic but it's returing error as  invalid string for converting to date

```
... t:TO_DATE
```

My logic: I have a fixed width flat file source with data like `2016090120160931` which has start and end dates. Looks like start date is pull good but not the end date

```
Input :End_Date_YYYYMMDD(string) 8='20160931'
variable:set_$$END_DATE(date/time) = IIF(End_Date_YYYYMMDD != '00000000',TO_DATE(End_Date_YYYYMMDD,'YYYYMMDD'),
ADD_TO_DATE(LAST_DAY( SYSDATE ),'MM',-1)
)---------this  is where its showing error

variable: set_$$END_DATE_v(string)8 =to_char(set_$$END_DATE,'YYYYMMDD')
output: $$END_DATE(string)8=SETVARIABLE($$END_DATE,set_$$END_DATE_v)
```

Please help, Kiran

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
LAST_DAY(ADD_TO_DATE(SYSDATE,'MM',-1))
```